# Article won't stay above rest of siblings when resized

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm designing a blog. It has a featured article that's expanded to full screen with other article thumbnails displayed below. When one of the thumbnails is clicked, it must expand while the featured article shrinks into a thumbnail. The tricky part I ran into is making the article display above the rest of it's siblings on `click`. The only thing I could think of was adding a class called `.thumb` to all thumbnails not currently being featured. `.thumb` includes the style `align-items: baseline` but that doesn't seem to work either. The problem is easier understood by looking at the example. You'll see the problem right away by clicking on any of the thumbnails. 'Article 1' always displays above the featured article. I know that this is more of a CSS question than jQuery but I couldn't think of a good title sorry. Thanks for looking at this, here's my code:

```js
$( "div[id^='block-']" ).click(function() {
    $( "div[id^='block-']" ).addClass( "thumb" );
    $( "div[id^='block-']" ).removeClass( "featured" );
   $( this ).removeClass( "thumb" );
    $( this ).addClass( "featured" );
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container {
 width: 75vw;
 margin: 24px auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image {
 height: 50%;
 background: skyblue;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

.content {
 font-size: 8px;
 font-family: Arial;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 8px;
}

.featured {
 width: calc(100% - 32px);
 margin: 16px 16px 0;
}

.thumb {
 align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="container">
 
 <div id="block-1" class="block featured">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
   ARTICLE 1<br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="block-2" class="block thumb">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
   ARTICLE 2<br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="block-3" class="block thumb">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
   ARTICLE 3<br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="block-4" class="block thumb">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
   ARTICLE 4<br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="block-5" class="block thumb">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
   ARTICLE 5<br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it will not do anything great with your animations, but you position the featured one absolute inside the parent.

```
.container { 
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 140px;
}

.featured {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

But you will have to work on transitions that look better than what you have.